# I try to change the element.style by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code:

```
var fadelft = function(cm){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(cm).offset().top)
    {
        $(cm).animate({'left': '0%'}, 1000);
    }else{
        $(cm).css('left', '50%');
    }
}
```

I use this function in the [`$("window").scroll()`](https://yokeyang.github.io/xdf.github.io/usmaster/Main.js) function.
However the else part works every time but it quick change to '0'.

I know there must have some problems in my scroll function, but I don't know how to do this.
[Live link (Chinese)](https://yokeyang.github.io/xdf.github.io/usmaster/Main.html)

Comment: Don't bother for your English. we are developers not grammar nazi

Comment: can you create an example link to see your problem exactly.

Comment: sorrry link : https://yokeyang.github.io/xdf.github.io/usmaster/Main.html and it is chinese